# Redirecting to error page when path is invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to redirect to an error page I created whenever the user puts an invalid path on my application. Let's say the user puts domain.com/efneroguqf or any random path.

Here's my App function inside App.js

```
function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Suspense fallback={(<div>Loading</div>)}>
          <Navbar />
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/SignUp" component={SignUp} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/Publish" component={Publish} />
          <Route path="/AdminGenerator" component={AdminGenerator} />
          <Route path="/AdminUsers" component={AdminUsers} />
          <Route path="/List" component={List} />
          <Route path="/publication" component={Details} />
          <Route path="/error" component={ErrorBoundary} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/MyPublications" component={MyPublications} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/MyFavorites" component={MyFavorites} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/MyInformation" component={MyInformation} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/EditPublication" component={EditPublication} />
          <Route exact path="*" component={Home} />
        </Suspense>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </div>

  );
}
```

Now I want to redirect to /error in case the path is invalid like I mentioned above. How can I achieve that?

Update: Here's my error page. I want to set the coding to 404 when this happens.

```
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            coding: props.location.state.coding
        };
    }

    render(){
        const { t } = this.props;
            var codeMsg = t('errors.errorCode') + this.state.coding 
            return ( 
                <div>
                    <div id="error-container">
                        <h1 id="error-title">{t('errors.errorTitle')}</h1>          
                        <p id="error-status">{codeMsg}</p>      
                        <p id="error-message">{t('errors.errorMessage')}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="link2-container">
                    <a href="/" id="error-link1">{t('errors.errorBackHome')}</a>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            );     
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <Switch>
  ...
  <Route component={Error} />
<Switch />
```

If you render a `Route` but don’t specify a path prop, that route will always be rendered.

Comment: What if I want to pass the error code to my page? I just updated my post.

Comment: The problem with that is that the server will not respond with a status code of 404. This is client side routing you are implementing. There isn't any error to forward, this is a "Page not found" for all routes that are not specified.

Answer (score 2):

As the very last path, use a wildcard..

```
// last path in route list
<Route path="*" component={NotFoundPage} />
```

***With 404 page:***

```js
const { Component } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;
const { Switch, Route, Link, HashRouter, withRouter } = ReactRouterDOM;

class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to='/'>Home</Link></li>
          <li><Link to='/about'>About</Link></li>
          <li><Link to='/contact'>Contact</Link></li>
          <li><Link to='/iDontReallyExist'>Simulate Non-existent route</Link></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <main>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage}/>
          <Route path='/about' component={AboutPage}/>
          <Route path='/contact' component={ContactPage}/>
          <Route path='*' component={FourZeroFour}/>
        </Switch>
      </main>
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>Home Page</div>
    );
  }
}

class AboutPage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>About Page</div>
    );
  }
}

class ContactPage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>Contact Page</div>
    );
  }
}

class SomeNonExistentRoute extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>I dont exist</div>
    );
  }
}

class FourZeroFour extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>Uh oh can't find that! 404!</div>
    );
  }
}

class Application extends Component {
  render() {
    let curRoute = this.props.location.pathname
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <p>Current Route: {curRoute}</p>
        <Main />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const App = withRouter(Application);

render((
  <HashRouter>
    <App />
  </HashRouter>
), document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router-dom/5.1.2/react-router-dom.min.js"></script>
```

***With Home page as '404':***

```js
const { Component } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;
const { Switch, Route, Link, HashRouter, withRouter } = ReactRouterDOM;

class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to='/'>Home</Link></li>
          <li><Link to='/about'>About</Link></li>
          <li><Link to='/contact'>Contact</Link></li>
          <li><Link to='/iDontReallyExist'>Simulate Non-existent route</Link></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <main>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage}/>
          <Route path='/about' component={AboutPage}/>
          <Route path='/contact' component={ContactPage}/>
          <Route path='*' component={HomePage}/>
        </Switch>
      </main>
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>Home Page</div>
    );
  }
}

class AboutPage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>About Page</div>
    );
  }
}

class ContactPage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>Contact Page</div>
    );
  }
}

class SomeNonExistentRoute extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>I dont exist</div>
    );
  }
}

class FourZeroFour extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>Uh oh can't find that! 404!</div>
    );
  }
}

class Application extends Component {
  render() {
    let curRoute = this.props.location.pathname
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <p>Current Route: {curRoute}</p>
        <Main />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const App = withRouter(Application);

render((
  <HashRouter>
    <App />
  </HashRouter>
), document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router-dom/5.1.2/react-router-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: For some reason when I do that, every path goes to my error page

Comment: It needs to be the ***very last*** route in your route list.

Comment: I think I have a problem with render, since I want to pass the error code to my error page (in this case 404). I just updated my post.

Comment: If the route is not found then the error code should always be 404.. What error is there to pass? You should create a default 404 page/component and point the wildcard path to that component/page.

Comment: Technically, as far as your app is concerned there isn't any error. The wildcard route is just another route. Everything is working as it should as far as your app is concerned. Just that you wish to use the catch-all route for a 404 page. You could technically use anything there just like any other route could point to any component. You could point the wildcard route to whatever component you're using as your home page... Again it's just a other route and there won't be any errors.

Comment: The reason you were getting an error before is because no catch-all/404/wildcard route existed. Now that one exists just point it to a default 404 component.

Comment: Thank you I get what you're saying. Now just to try it out, I used your proposal redirecting to my Home site. Turns out I get the site rendered 3 times when I get to home and when I use the path for any of my other sites I also get home rendered and below that my actual page.

Comment: You shouldn't redirect. Just use the same component. If you redirect it will cause the behavior you explained.

Comment: I think I expressed myself wrong, I meant I just added that line (just updated my question) and get the issue I explained.

Comment: That's because your `Routes` render inclusively. Every `Route` path that matches the location will render and your last one catches all locations. Wrap the entire thing in a `Swtich` component. `Switch` renders a route exclusively, that being the first child that matches the location. React elements you always want to render on every location need to be before or after `Swtich`

Comment: Thanks a lot to both actually.

Comment: @Stackoverflowed sorry about that I was coming back from lunch and wanted to get an example/demo created for you.. I have updated my answer with the demo, although it appears you have got this sorted out...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React v6+, instead of the component we have to use element in Route.
And you can specify the error page functional component as shown below:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import './App.css';
    import Login from './component/Login';
    import Register from './component/Register';
    import Home from './component/Home'
    import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
    
    
    class App extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <BrowserRouter>
              <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Login/>}></Route>
                <Route path="/register" element={<Register/>}></Route>
                <Route path="/home" element={<Home/>}></Route>
                <Route path="*" element={<ErrorComponent/>}></Route>
              </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    
    function ErrorComponent(){
      return <div>Some error occured. Invalid page</div>
    }
    
    export default App;
```